# VBA to extract SQL code out of MS Access dbase

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am new to VBA & Access so please excuse my question

I  need to document a colleague's access dbase, all his queries, forms and especially reports. Ideally I will recreate the reports in VBA with lots of comments to explain the calculation (or variables relationship).

I found Saveastext and other procedures using codes (from [VBA to extract SQL code out of MS Access dbase, however the characters end up unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551731/vba-to-extract-sql-code-out-of-ms-access-dbase-however-the-characters-end-up-un))

However, I am still stuck on how to translate the exported texts to VBA & how to comment on these texts.

Is there any script/program I can use for the translation? I assume once I understand the text i can learn to write some VBA and then liberally add comments. At least, can someone explain to me what encoding is this I see throughout the exported files (for example 0x0acc0e550000000015c10222b88a014db58df975d29c811d0000000088184de2)

If there is no translation and the texts are all i have to work with, is there a way of adding comments to that? Or is it forbidden like SQL? I tried adding some comments but I could not use LoadFromText with the inserted comments afterwards.

Any lead would be extremely helpful

Cheers

Comment: Please post a sample of the text files you have been able to export that you want to migrate to vba

Comment: I'm sorry i cant postVersion =20
VersionRequired =20
PublishOption =1
Checksum =-88494015
Begin Report
    LayoutForPrint = NotDefault
    DividingLines = NotDefault
    AllowAdditions = NotDefault
    AllowDesignChanges = NotDefault
    DateGrouping =1
    GrpKeepTogether =1
    PictureAlignment =2
    DatasheetGridlinesBehavior =3
    GridX =24
    GridY =24
    Width =3795
    DatasheetFontHeight =11
    ItemSuffix =13
    Left =5040
    Top =10950
    Right =9360
    Bottom =11280
    DatasheetGridlinesColor =14806254
    RecSrcDt = Begin
        0xeb920fadae95e440
    End
    GUID = Begin

Answer (score 0):

Reports, forms, macros even queries are really non-data, design UI objects in MS Access. As such, they would not have translatable, readable object-oriented programming code in Access.

`SaveAsText`and `LoadAsText` (unlisted methods on the MSDN site) is most likely used for dump storage of these application items for backup and migration purposes not document-ready or code-ready for human consumption. To be clear, these files are not VBA and not SQL code, nor XML markup.

Consider browsing their content for properties and specifications, and not directly modifying or commenting such files, else they will no longer be functional.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, then how would one go about documenting the queries and report specs?

Comment: Each Access query simply contain one SQL statement either an action or select. Simply, open and read them, noting the fields, tables, and joins. And same for reports, open and verify the structure, noting the grouping, sorting, table/query recordsources.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code time ago, I don't remember where, but I used it to extract.
Just create the file in the destination path first.

```
Public Sub ExtractSQL()

Dim db As DAO.Database, qdef As DAO.Querydef
Dim qrys As Variant, qry As Variant
Dim strSQL As String, sqlFile As String

Set db = CurrentDb
qrys = Array("Step1", "Step2")

sqlFile = "[filepath]\AllQueries.sql"

' OPEN SQL TEXT FILE
Open sqlFile For Output As #1

For Each qdef In db.QueryDefs
    For Each qry In qrys

        If qdef.Name = qry Then
                Print #1, qdef.SQL      ' SQL STATEMENT
                Print #1, ""            ' LINE SEPARATOR
        End If

    Next qry
Next qdef

' CLOSE SQL TEXT FILE
Close #1
Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub